# Extract separate double values from string value visual basic. Net

Tags: string, vb.net, double, extract

I'm trying here to extract double values 3.6, 2.4, 4.8 separately - each one into a separate text box- from this string text “3.6 (2.4 to 4.8)”

```
Dim A as string = textbox1.text ' "3.6 (2.4 to 4.8)" 
Textbox2.text = value1' 3.6
Textbox3.text = value2' 2.4
Textbox4.text = value3' 4.8
```

Thanks in advance :)

An update

I searched and tried to use this code

```
Dim A as string = textbox1.text ' "3.6 (2.4 to 4.8)" 
Dim M as Match = Regex.Match(A, "\d+(?:[.,]\d+) *") 
If M.Success Then
Dim R1 = M.groups(0).value
Textbox2.text = R1 ' 3.6
```

But i don't know how to extract other 2 values

Comment: What have you tried and how is it not working?

Comment: Honeyboy Wilson I searched and tried to use this code
```
Dim A as string = textbox1.text ' "3.6 (2.4 to 4.8)" 
Dim M as Match = Regex.Match(A, "\d+(?:[.,]\d+) *") 
If M.Success Then
Dim R1 = M.groups(0).value
Textbox2.text = R1
```
But i don't know how to extract other 2 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code and it works for me:

```
Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text, "\d+(?:[.,]\d+) *")
Dim texts(2) As String ' Specifically assigns for 0, 1, 2 (3 elements)
Dim index As Byte = 0 ' Index increment-er

For Each m As Match In mc
    texts(index) = m.ToString ' Writes texts(0... 1... 2...) with m1, m2, m3
    index += 1
Next

TextBox2.Text = texts(0) ' Output
TextBox3.Text = texts(1)
TextBox4.Text = texts(2)
```